# Where does moodle 2.x save courses backups?

Tags: mysql, moodle

I have to create a course in a moodle project that exist in another moodle project.

I have created a backup of the course I need, but I can't find where the file was created and in the moodle it shows me the backup.

I have read that in the `mdl_data` table or `mdl_backup_controllers` have info about where the file its but my `mdl_data` has no records and `mdl_backup_controllers` has the course id but I don't know how that help; it only shows a hashed field named `backupid` that doesn't exist in the other tables.

Comment: Spelling; grammar.

Answer (score 0):

When a back up file is created , it creates an entry in **mdl_files** table.

there is one column "**contetnhash**".

that column contain the file information and location.

let say content hash **da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709so** location would be

```
<dataroot>/filedire/da/39/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709so
```

**first four character divided in two two parts** would be directory.